# Powershell for checking reboot status after installing windows updates

Tags: powershell, windows-update

Here is the code i am using for searching Windows updates installed by WSUS, I want to add one more column for the status of reboot pending/done. Is there a switch for that?

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"

$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()

$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()

$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Date,

   @{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){

       1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}}}},

   @{name="Status"; expression={switch($_.resultcode){

       1 {"In Progress"}; 2 {"Succeeded"}; 3 {"Succeeded With Errors"};

       4 {"Failed"}; 5 {"Aborted"}

}}}, Title | Out-GridView
```

Comment: I dont think that we have any specific switch for checking the reboot status. I think we have to check that explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brief look at the COM object properties and methods does not show anything for this. [You can query update *before* to see if they might trigger a reboot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but it is not a guarantee of how the client will react.

There might be other ways but if you want to know for sure of the current state one suggestion would be to look in the registry.

[If a patch was installed by WindowsUpdates that requires a reboot it should leave a registry entry in this location](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hansr/2006/02/17/how-to-detect-if-a-reboot-is-needed-after-installing-a-patch/):

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired`

So you just need to check if there are *any* values in that key to know its pending state as far as WU is concerned.

```
$pendingRebootKey = "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired"
$results = (Get-Item $pendingRebootKey -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Property

if($results){
    # Reboot is pending
}
```

Using `-ErrorAction` is useful since, according to the article:

> Note that the 
>   RebootRequired key is automatically deleted when the machine reboots as it's 
>   volatile (only held in memory).

This could hide other potential issues so you might need to change the logic to a try/catch and look at the specific error for things like `ItemNotFoundException` if there is concern there.

Comment: how can I add this to my current output as a new column? a new object?

Comment: This is executed on the host machine correct? You current output list updates. While you might be able to connect the updates to the registry data I am not sure how to add this in a satisfactory way for you. You could add another calculated property but it is a property of the running computer not the updates you are querying.